# Percentage of users that get to business website by searching vs typing business url into address bar

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search, local-seo, business

My friend's company(lets call it **SomeThingsAreWorthTheMoney** ) has been affected by a competitor's cybersquatting attack. **SomeThingsAreWorthTheMoney** is primarily an offline, real-world company that delivers real world services to local customers.

Its been around for well over 10 years and has been using a domain *stawtmoney.com*(again domain is made up) for a long time. Its direct competitor has acquired a domain name *SomeThingsAreWorthTheMoney.com* and has been selling its own real-world services to the customer in the same locale. Its been going on for at least a year until **SomeThingsAreWorthTheMoney** has found out.

So when you google for '**Some Things Are Worth The Money**"(name of the company, again made-up, with spaces), the actual company's site (*stawtmoney.com*) comes up in the results. However, when you type in the cybersquatted name(*somethingsareworththemoney.com*), the competitors website offering their services would come up.

My friend is looking to estimate what damages did his company receive due to this cybersquatting. One way to do this is to figure out a percentage of users usually get to the website they are looking for by typing in an address in the address bar vs typing in a company name in the search bar.

Are there any legitimate studies or reports that provide this sort of statistics?

Comment: IF you had "log stats" active on your hosting web server, you may also be able to retrieve this information.

Comment: What's being asked is a "Closing the barn door after the horses got out" type of scenario. Google Analytics being used over this time could have provided it. If the owner was saving log files for this period of time, same thing. It's difficult to find out after the fact and after the data has expired out.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) offers the option of viewing Direct Traffic (typing on the address bar), Organic, Referral and Paid traffic under the HOME tab.

It'll only give you data from the moment you sign up on, so if you don't have an account yet, I'm afraid it won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend's company name is competitive keyword, i recommend using this Google adword https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool

Or you can get this information with the help of Google adword account, follow below steps:

1. Create account with Google adwords
2. Add keyword which you want to monitor and create Google search ads on those keywords. (target only google search - no display ads or no partner network).
3. Bid high on that keywords so it can achieve 1 position
4. Run this campaign for 3-4 days (24 hours a day)
5. Now check number of impression on that keyword (it will give you number of searches done by visitors on that keywords).
6. You can also calculate cost of advertisement and potential earning you can generate if you can achieve that search engine rankings.

I am sure it will help !!